# Change the date format to "dd/mm/yyyy" to all date columns (in the same columns itself) in an excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel workbook which has SAP BEx Analysis for Office queries.  Currently when I refresh the SAP BEx Analysis for Office queries, date columns in that query are taking the Operating system regional date settings.

Ex: If my operating system default date setting is set to mm/dd/yyyy,
then when the queries are refreshed, it will show in the same format i.e. mm/dd/yyyy.

Once the query is refreshed, then if I use the `.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyy"` then it is not changing.

There is an another option which is If I add the code mentioned below to workbook open , then in another column I need to add the following code `=FMT(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy")` it will then convert correctly.

```
Public Function FMT$(ByVal Value, ByVal strFormat)
    FMT = VBA.Format$(Value, strFormat)
End Function
```

However I don't want to convert the date format in another column.  All date columns should get updated to "dd/mm/yyyy" format in the workbook.

Is there a better / easiest way of changing the date format to "dd/mm/yyyy" in the same columns where the dates are mentioned through VBA or any other method?

I have dates in 3 columns in one worksheet and 1 column in another worksheet.

Comment: You need to change the date format in the query itself to match your windows regional settings.

Comment: No, there is no option to change date format in the SAP BEx AAO Query

Comment: I don't use that tool. But a brief internet search turned up [this](https://answers.sap.com/questions/654867/date-format-in-analysis-for-excel.html). Does that not apply to you?

Comment: No, I tried all possible options and didn't work.

Comment: If changing the `.NumberFormat` property of the cell does not change the appearance, then the cell contains a text string and not a "real date". If `=FMT(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy")=FMT(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy")` works correctly all of the time, and the developer of the add-in won't provide a proper Excel date, then you can run a macro that loops through that column, replacing each string date with a real date and applying the desired `.NumberFormat`.

Comment: When I run a macro, it is taking more than 1 minute for each column and I have 4 columns which is taking 4 minutes if I loop the formula. Is there a better way to speed up the macro?  I have used the following vba code to do the looping and update the date format ```Sub ConvertDates
 Dim r as range
 For each r in selection
      r.formula = format(r.value,"dd.mm.yyyy")
 next r
 end sub```

Comment: Read the range into a vba array; process each array element; write the array back to the worksheet. See [Vba arrays and worksheet ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx). If that doesn't help, post your code on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site for assistance.